# html and css for lists without `<span class` for each item

Tags: html, css

As my university needs me to make my publication list. As I have very little experience with html+css, I am bit stuck here.
What I am currently doing is:

### CSS Part

```
p.bibitem { text-indent: -2em; margin-left: 2em; margin-top:0.6em; margin-bottom:0.6em; }
p.bibitem-p { text-indent: 0em; margin-left: 2em; margin-top:0.6em; margin-bottom:0.6em; }
.bibauth{font-weight : bold;}
.bibtitle{font-style : italic;}
.bibpub{font-style : normal;}
```

### HTML Part

```
<div class="thebibliography">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <p class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel">
                <span class="bibauth">Name of the authors</span> 
                <span class="bibtitle">Title of the paper</span>
              <span class="pub">Publication info</span> 
            </p>
      </li>
```

I have converted my publication list from `latex` using `htlatex`, and not sure if the line class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel"> is really required. In html, they are not making much difference. But the rest of the thing looks well.

**It will be helpful if you kindly comment if there is any error, hidden**

But my main concern is slightly more involved for me.
Can I define a structure in CSS, so that, without repeating the `span class`thing for each item, it will pick up each `new line` as the next structure? i.e.,say,

```
<div class="TheMagicDiv">
Name of Authors
Title of Paper
Publecation Info
</div>
```

will automatically pick up `bibauth`, `bibtitle` and `bibpub` and result in something like[image: this]

May be something as `object-oriented html`?

Comment: Solutions below. However, to answer your last question to the letter: yes, it is possible to display those three lines of plain text on a line of their own each, by using `white-space:pre-line`. Since they are not three elements, you can't style all three lines differently though; that's not how CSS works.

Comment: But in a surprise move, CSS _does_ allow you to style the first line of those three, by using the `:first-line` pseudo-element. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/M3d9a/) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have alot of obsolete code, i've tried to remove the unnessary code and optimized your CSS to fit the need.

Your CSS:

```
.bibitem .pub{font-family: Tahoma;display: block;font-style : normal;font-size: 13px;}

.bibitem .bibauth{color:blue;display: block;font-weight : bold;font-size: 16px;}

.bibitem .bibtitle{color: grey;display: block;font-style : italic;}
```

Your HTML:

```
    <ol>
    <li>
        <p class="bibitem" >
            <span class="bibauth">Name of the authors</span> 
            <span class="bibtitle">Title of the paper</span>
            <span class="pub">Publication info</span> 
        </p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Result:
http://jsfiddle.net/4B3gV/2/

Comment: So every element within the bibitem is inherited by your spans

Answer (score 1):

`.biblabel` doesn't appear to have any styles defined for it, so it's making no difference to your result.

Unfortunately you can't have newlines be identified as items in this way... you will need separate elements.

Comment: So, for you, what I am doing is acceptable way of doing this?

Comment: Yup. It's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `<span class="biblabel">` is not closed anywhere so it makes your html invalid.
(*and you have not defined any class `biblabel` in your CSS so you can remove that tag altogether*)

Not sure you need the `p` as well.. you could apply the `class="bibitem"` to the `li` elements in order to simplify your html.

```
<li class="bibitem">
      <span class="bibauth">Name of the authors</span> 
      <span class="bibtitle">Title of the paper</span>
      <span class="pub">Publication info</span> 
</li>
```

For the ***magic div*** it is not possible..

For the new line for each item just add `.bibitem > span{display:block;}`

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jcXad/